# Bind TextBox in ASP.NET aspx from Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i have a webform page with textBox control and button, when i click at button the form is posted to server then i trying to bind a string value to my text box but unsuccessfully:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txbName" runat="server" CssClass="k-textbox">
```

code behind:

```
txbName.Text = "myName";
```

can some one give an example of how can i do it?

Comment: Can you please provide code for the button click event?

Comment: Usman Khalid, my button click event is same as the answer of christos

Comment: What have you done to try and debug the problem? For example, have you set a breakpoint in the debugger on your line in the code behind and, if so, is it reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the event you are trying to set it on:

```
txbName.Text = "myName";

if(!IsPostBack)  
{
txbName.DataBind();
}
```

This works on page load and will write over the other settings

Comment: Yap, the problem was that i´ve been doing txtName.Text = "myName"; after Page_Load method, when i rewrite code to the page_load it worked well, thanks!